# What is the Spirit of Jesus?

Tags: acts

Acts 16:7
When they came to the border of Mysia, they tried to enter Bithynia, but the **Spirit of Jesus** would not allow them to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Spirit of Jesus" is also called (as per Acts 16:7) is also known as the "Spirit of God" and the "Spirit of Christ" and the "Holy Spirit" and also just the "Spirit".  Observe the following:

- Rom 8:9 - You, however, are controlled not by the flesh, but by the **Spirit**, if the **Spirit of God** lives in you. And if anyone does not have the **Spirit of Christ**, he does not belong to Christ.
- John 16:13-15 - However, when the **Spirit of truth** comes, He will guide you into all truth. For He will not speak on His own, but He will speak what He hears, and He will declare to you what is to come. He will glorify Me by taking from what is Mine and disclosing it to you. Everything that belongs to the Father is Mine. That is why I said that the **Spirit** will take from what is Mine and disclose it to you.
- Gal 4:6 - And because you are sons, God sent the **Spirit of His Son** into our hearts, crying out, “Abba, Father!”
- Phil 1:19 - for I know that through your prayers and God's provision of the **Spirit of Jesus Christ** what has happened to me will turn out for my deliverance.
- 1 Peter 1:11 - trying to determine the time and setting to which the **Spirit of Christ** in them was pointing when He predicted the sufferings of Christ and the glories to follow.
- Matt 10:20 - for it will not be you speaking, but the **Spirit of your Father** speaking through you.
- 1 Cor 3:16 - Do you not know that you yourselves are God’s temple, and that **God’s Spirit** dwells in you?
- John 14:26 - But the **Advocate**, the **Holy Spirit**, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have said to you.
- 2 Peter 1:21 - For no such prophecy was ever brought forth by the will of man, but men spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit.

... and so forth.  The Holy Spirit is the One who teaches us about Christ and enables us to understand spiritual things.  He is the One who inspired the prophets to write the Scriptures.  See also John 16:5-16 for information about the work of the Holy Spirit or "Comforter" or "Advocate", etc.

Answer (score 3):

**What is the Spirit of Jesus?**

> Acts 16:7 When they came to the border of Mysia, they tried to enter
> Bithynia, but the Spirit of Jesus would not allow them to.

Apparently, Jesus used the holy spirit that He received from the Father (Acts 2:33 read below)  to prevent Paul and his companions from preaching in the Asian province of Bithynia, this indicated to them that they should concentrate their efforts to preaching in more productive regions.

Acts 2:33 (NASB)

> 33 Therefore, since He has been exalted at the right hand of God, and
> has received the promise of the Holy Spirit from the Father, He has
> poured out this which you both see and hear.

The holy spirit is the Power of the Most High, said the angel Gabriel to Mary.

J.Moffat Luke 1:34,35

> 34" Mary said to the angel, “How can this be, since I am a virgin?” 35
> "The angel answered her, ***"The holy Spirit will come upon you, the
> power of the Most High will overshadow you;*** hence what is born will be
> called holy, Son of God."

And Luke 4:14  NASB   Says:

> Jesus started his ministry ***in the power of the spirit.***  " And Jesus
> returned to Galilee in the power of the Spirit, and news about Him
> spread through all the surrounding district."

Luke 4:14  NASB

J. Moffat Acts 1:8"

> Jesus promised his  Apostles that they will receive power when the
> holy Spirit comes upon you. "***You will receive power when the holy
> Spirit comes upon you***, and you will be my witnesses at Jerusalem,
> throughout all Judaea and Samaria, and to the end of the earth."

**Conclusion**

The holy spirit is the power of the Most High

Spirit of the Lord  (Luke 4:18 NASB), spirit (Numb. 11:25  NRSV) Holy spirit (Luke 1:15  NASB) Spirit of Jesus (Acts 16:7) all refer to the same spirit, the holy spirit, the angel Gabriel summed it up very well when he said to Mary, the holy spirit is the power of the Most High.

God takes a share of the spirit that was upon Moses  and places it upon the  seventy elders

Numbers 11:25  (RSVCE)

> 25 Then the Lord came down in the cloud and spoke to him, and ***took
> some of the spirit that was upon him and put it upon the seventy
> elders;*** and when the spirit rested upon them, they prophesied. But
> they did so no more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given by Dottard got most of it right, except for the conclusion.

The Spirit of God, or the Spirit of Christ or the Holy Spirit all these three mean the same thing. But the  Spirit is not a separate entity as so many human beings want it to be.

Every time the Greek word is translated for the verses talking of the Spirit of God, 'he' is used in place of 'it', because the Greek language did not have a neuter term to refer to a thing. It always had to be a 'he' or a 'she'. Just like in so many languages, other than English.

Comment: Actually, this is factually and grammatically incorrect - Greek has an array of neuter pronouns, namely, auto = it, touto = this, etc; all in their full declensions.  In John 16:13 ἐκεῖνος = "he"  is used NOT ἐκεῖνο ="it".

Comment: Leslie  +1 You're correct, the Greek word "hagion pneuma" is neuter and in the Greek language, it is never and I stress never referred to it with personal pronouns he/ who/whom, Bibles doing so are theologically biased. Do not be dismayed by the down vote..

Comment: @OzzieOzzie - Again, this factually wrong - John 16:13 uses ἐκεῖνος = "he" which is male first person nominative singular.  Please examine the facts as they are rather than the way would would want them to be.

Comment: @ Dottard : that one: Both “that one” and “he” in verses 13 and 14 refer back to “the helper” mentioned at John 16:7. Jesus used “the helper” (which is in the masculine gender in Greek) as a personification of the holy spirit, an impersonal force, which is in the neuter gender in Greek.​

Comment: @LeslieLawrence http://www.ibiblio.org/koine/greek/lessons/pronoun2.html

Comment: Answers are for answering the question, not for agreeing that someone else has "got it mostly right except for..." then offering a correction to another answerer. That turns it into a platform for promoting one's own particular slant on the matter, which the OP did not ask for. There are other questions on here about whether the Holy Spirit is a separate entity or not, or whether this is a reference to Mohammed or not etc.